# How to build Snappy Ubuntu Core from source to binary?

Tags: compiling, ubuntu-core

I followed the link below and run the Snappy on my Intel platform.

[Try_x86](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/#try-x86)

The system can boot and works works okay.

I know this is a generic image for x86 platform and must contain some unnecessary drivers, packages which I dont need on my working platform.

However, is there any tutorial or instruction that I can follow to build the source code to the binary ? The general amd64 kernel containing all packages is okay to me.

After doing this, I can start removing some unnecessary things from the source.

Please provide your advice.  Thanks

Comment: any idea? I have been searching around for awhile but nothing can be found so far. any comment is appreciated.